# SQL Server developer edition maximum size capacity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to develop a local intranet application where the back end is SQL SERVER DEVELOPMENT EDITION. And this application is keeping all the internal employee's data. Every week new data will be saved into this database. So here I would like to know one thing, what is the maximum data that SQL SERVER DEVELOPMENT EDITION can support? I will deploy this application on my laptop. So is this storage dependent on my hard disk size of my laptop.

Also which developer edition I should install?

Comment: Developer Edition is **not** legally allowed to be used in a production system ..... if you need a **production** database, you'll need to get a license for a Web, Standard or Enterprise edition of SQL Server - or use the **free** Express version which is limited to 10 GB max database size in the 2008 R2/2012/2014 versions.

Comment: According to the [SQL Server Maximum Capacity Specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), a database can be a maximum of **16 TB** (terabytes - 16'384 GB)

Comment: Too broad- this is a field people take serious planning for and the explanatins fill easily a book. A senior developer should decide that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

marc_s mentioned a 16TB limit but that is per file rather than per database.  The database size limit in Developer Edition is 524,272 terabytes.  But the bigger issue is that this seems to be a production application so Developer Edition is not an option from a licensing perspective.